# How to compare all values of a list in python?

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, series

This is my code:

```
ticker = 'NFLX'
price = get_data(ticker, start_date='2020-01-01', end_date=None, index_as_date=bool, interval ='1d')
price.to_csv(r'D:\Python Stuff\pythonProject\NFLX.csv')
df = pd.read_csv('NFLX.csv')
price_list = df['adjclose']

def SMA():

    SMA_days = 20
    sma = price_list.rolling(window=SMA_days).mean()
    combined = pd.DataFrame()
    combined['adjclose'] = price['adjclose']
    combined['SMA'] = sma
    return sma
simple_moving_average = SMA()
    
lowest_rsi = min(relative_strength_index[-6:])
lowest_rsi_index = np.argmin(relative_strength_index[-6:])
print(lowest_rsi_index)
print(lowest_rsi)

print(price_list[-6:])
print(simple_moving_average[-6:])

if all(np.array(list(price_list[-6:])) > np.array(list(simple_moving_average[-6:]))):
    if abs(price_list[-1] - simple_moving_average[-1])<=1.5:
        if lowest_rsi < 50:
            main()
```

When I run the code, the error is on the line which says: if all(np.array(list(price_list[-6:])) > np.array(list(simple_moving_average[-6:])))

I want the if condition to proceed when all value of all the elements in price_list is greater than the value of all the elements in simple_moving_average. How do I fix this?

Comment: Is there a typo here: if all(np.array(list(price_list[-6:])) > np.array(list(simple_moving_average[-6]))). simple_moving_average[-6]) should be simple_moving_average[-6:])?

Comment: yes my mistake. i fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You can change your if-statement to `if (price_list[-6:] > simple_moving_average[-6:]).all():`

Comment: I get this: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: If `price_list` and `simple_moving_average` are the type of pd.Series, copy and paste my code should work. Otherwise, please kindly check the datatype of these two variables.

Comment: they are both of the type pd.Series